# Group nested links by first-level iframe using casperjs

Tags: javascript, iframe, casperjs

**I have the following code:**

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
        //  verbose: true,
        //    logLevel: "debug",
        webSecurityEnabled : false
    });
var links = [];
function get_links(obj) {
    return obj.evaluate(function () {
        var i,
            l = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
            l2 = [];
        for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            l2[i] = l[i].href;
        }
        return l2
    });
}
function unique(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (/http(.*)?/.test(arr[i])) {
            var str = arr[i];
            obj[str] = true;
        }
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}

function getLinksFromIframes(callback) {
    this.echo("Here we come: " + this.getCurrentUrl() + "\n");
    function to_frame(obj) {
        var iframes = to_evaluate(obj);
        iframes.forEach(function (index) {
            this.withFrame(index, function () {
                this.echo("We are here: " + this.getCurrentUrl());
                var l = unique(get_links(this));
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                    console.log(l[i]);
                    links.push(l[i])
                }
                links = unique(links);
                console.log("");
                to_frame(this)
            });
        }, obj);
    }
    function to_evaluate(obj) {
        return obj.evaluate(function () {
            var iframes = [];
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function (iframe, i) {
                iframes.push(i);
            });
            return iframes;
        })
    }
    to_frame(this);
    this.then(function () {
        callback.call(this);
    });
}

casper.start("http://domu-test-2/node/1", function () {
    getLinksFromIframes.call(this, function () {
        console.log("Done!\n");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            console.log(links[i]);
        }
    });
}).then(function () {}).run();
```

**And now the question is:**

if I want get links by the first-level iframe, how should I refactor the `getLinksFromIframes()` function. Currently they share a 'global' variable `links`. I think definitely the `links` will be list of link list and initialize new list within `withFrame` function, then pass this new reference to child iframes. So how should I pass it and 'backtrace' all links in nested iframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it correctly, you want to select which iframe from you get the links and only from that iframe. If that's the case, then you can simple use `switchToChildFrame` to switch to the desired iframe and then just get the links by calling `get_links(obj)`.

My example has 3 pages. An `index.html` that load `iframe1.html` inside an iframe and `iframe1.html` has another iframe inside that loads `iframe2.html`. Each file has 3 links inside:

**index.html**

```
<a href="link1/from/index">Link 1 from index</a>
<a href="link2/from/index">Link 2 from index</a>
<a href="link3/from/index">Link 3 from index</a>

<iframe src="iframe1.html"></iframe>
```

**iframe1.html**

```
<a href="link1/from/iframe1">Link 1 from iframe 1</a>
<a href="link2/from/iframe1">Link 2 from iframe 1</a>
<a href="link3/from/iframe1">Link 3 from iframe 1</a>

<iframe src="iframe2.html"></iframe>
```

**iframe2.html**

```
<a href="link1/from/iframe2">Link 1 from iframe 2</a>
<a href="link2/from/iframe2">Link 2 from iframe 2</a>
<a href="link3/from/iframe2">Link 3 from iframe 2</a>
```

and the refactored `getLinksFromIframes` function would be like this:

```
function getLinksFromIframes(callback) {
    this.echo("Here we come: " + this.getCurrentUrl() + "\n");

    function to_frame(obj) {
        obj.echo("We are here: " + obj.getCurrentUrl());
        var l = unique(get_links(obj));
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
            console.log(l[i]);
            links.push(l[i])
        }
        links = unique(links);
        console.log("");
    }
    function to_evaluate(obj) {
        return obj.evaluate(function () {
            var iframes = [];
            [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("iframe"), function (iframe, i) {
                iframes.push(i);
            });
            return iframes;
        })
    }

    // Leave both switchToChildFrame as comments to get the "index.html" links
    this.page.switchToChildFrame(0); // Uncomment to get the links of "iframe1.html"
    //this.page.switchToChildFrame(0); // Uncomment to get the links of "iframe2.html"
    to_frame(this);

    this.then(function () {
        callback.call(this);
    });
}
```

**RESULTS**

If you comment both `switchToChildFrame` you'll get the links of the `index.html`:

```
casperjs caspers-read-iframes.js
Here we come: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/

We are here: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/index
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/index
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/index

Done!

http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/index
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/index
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/index
```

If you uncomment the first `switchToChildFrame`, you'll get the links of the first level `iframe1.html`:

```
casperjs caspers-read-iframes.js
Here we come: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/

We are here: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/iframe1.html
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/iframe1
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/iframe1
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/iframe1

Done!

http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/iframe1
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/iframe1
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/iframe1
```

And if you uncomment both the first and the second `switchToChildFrame`, you'll get the links of the second level `iframe2.html`:

```
casperjs caspers-read-iframes.js
Here we come: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/

We are here: http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/iframe2.html
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/iframe2
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/iframe2
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/iframe2

Done!

http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link1/from/iframe2
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link2/from/iframe2
http://pjs.lytrax.net/node/1/link3/from/iframe2
```